# Redirecting Data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a project where all the data is going to one Postgres big table like:

| Time | ItemID | ItemType | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-16 | 1 | A | 2 |
| 2021-09-16 | 2 | B | 3 |
| 2021-09-17 | 3 | A | 3 |

My issue is this table is becoming very large. Since there are only 2 ItemTypes, I'd like to have `MyTableA` and `MyTableB` and the have a 3rd table with a one-to-one mapping of ItemID to ItemType.

What is the most performant way to insert the data and redirect to the respective table? I am currently thinking about creating a view with an INSTEAD OF trigger and then using two insert statements with joins to get the desired filtering. Is there a better way? Perhaps maintaining the ItemID_A/B in a array somewhere? Or should I figure out a way to do this client side?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "becoming very large"? The speed of selects or inserts will pretty much depend on your index strategy. Are the columns indexed? Would table partitioning be an option?

Comment: Have you looked at [Partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-partitioning.html)?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query that is slow together with the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` (as formatted text, not as a screen shot please)

Comment: The table currently has 14 billion rows and has a pk on time and ItemID